# Why do the agents knock on the doors?

Tags: realism, the-mentalist

While watching The Mentalist I observed that whenever the agents went to the families for interrogation, they always knocked on the door of the house to declare that they were there. In some of episodes they had this kinda hi-tech devices(like they could communicate through it).

where I live, it is common to have simple door-bells at the entrance, no knocking or that talking devices. So, what do the common people have in the US? No door bells? I don't think they knock these days. If so, then is there any reason why agents always knock the doors in The Mentalist?

Comment: Because doorbells don't always work and knocking does.

Comment: Sorry, but this is *way* too broad. Some people have doorbells, some have entry systems, some have neither.

Comment: And door intercoms are extremely popular in the UK/US/Europe.

Comment: The bigger the building or richer the occupants, the more likely the entry system. Single houses might consider a doorbell sufficient, or people can knock. There's just not enough 'fact' to sit any answer on, imo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a doorbell sound is much more audible inside the house, when the door is closed, while knocking on the door is easily heard by the TV ior movie audience, if the camera and audio perspective is on the agents, on the outside.

Plus, as comments mention, doorbells often don't work (I had to sell raffle tickets and collect newspaper route money in my childhood, so I know that, from house to house, doorbells were a hit/miss prospect, back then), so if you're going to do a knock and entry, you're required to give an opportunity for them to answer before breaching or going in by force.  Whether or not a doorbell is working adds an element of uncertainty, and can cause a delay, potentially, so simply knocking might just be the standard procedure for law enforcement.

Comment: At my house, people ring the bell then if I'm not at the door within 2.5 seconds, like I was standing behind it waiting for them, they bray on the door like it's a life or death emergency. Drives me bananas. Your point is fair, though. Cops don't have time or patience to see if the doorbell is working.

Comment: When Eight Ace's wife in _Viz_ said he wasn't a proper husband, he said 'I bray the kids for you, don't I?'